# Forçar 'www' e https na url - HTACCESS

Tags: apache, htaccess

Segue abaixo o código pra forçar o www e o https na url da página usando htaccess, quem precisar, pra mim funcionou certinho. Abraços

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.site\.com\.br$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.site.com.br/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Estou votando para fechar esta pergunta como fora de escopo porque não é uma pergunta.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Creio que usar `HTTP_HOST` seja melhor acaso venha a migrar ou aproveitar em múltiplos domínios e `REQUEST_URI` adiciona o caminho e a querystring

Diria que isto simplifica:

```bsh
# Redireciona para o HTTPS independente do domínio
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Adiciona www. no prefixo do domínio
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Guilherme, boa noite.

Mas ai fica só esse código? Não precisa passar a url? É que tem o domínio principal e os subdomínios.

Comment: @ThiagoFerreira `HTTP_HOST` é uma variável que contem o Host e o `REQUEST_URI` contem o path e a querystring, então não, não precisa. Como eu disse se vc mudar a de dominio fica mais fácil, não precisa ajustar nada no .htaccess