# Como redirecionar toda requisição HTTP para HTTPS no Silex?

Tags: https, silex

No Silex, há alguma possibilidade de fazer um filtro que redirecione uma a url para https quando a mesma não tem https?

Eu sei fazer isso no Laravel, mas gostaria de fazer a mesma operação com Silex.

Por exemplo, ao acessar a url `http://www.exemplo.com`, gostaria que redirecionasse para `https://www.exemplo.com`.

Como faço isso no Silex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme esta resposta no [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30618466/1518921) Creio que seja assim:

```php
$app = new Silex\Application();

$app['controllers']->requireHttps();

$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
    return 'Olá mundo!';
});

$app->run();
```

Documentação em [`Silex\Controller::requireHttps`](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/api/master/Silex/Controller.html#method_requireHttps)

> **Nota:**
>
> O Wallace deixou uma dica, se você estiver em ambiente de desenvolvimento HTTPS talvez não seja necessário, então você pode detectar se está o script está em modo de debug, assim:
>
> ```php
> $app = new Silex\Application();
>
> if (!$app['debug']) {
>    $app['controllers']->requireHttps();
> }
> ```
>
> Ou para simplificar assim:
>
> ```php
> $app = new Silex\Application();
>
> $app['debug'] || $app['controllers']->requireHttps();
> ```

Você também pode definir isto pelo `.htaccess` como expliquei em:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/184459/3635

Exemplo:

```bsh
# Redireciona para o HTTPS independente do domínio
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Adiciona www. no prefixo do domínio
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: A ideia é bacana, pena que tem que definir em rota por rota :\

Comment: @WallaceMaxters esse `requireHttps` é "estendido", creio que vc pode definir no `before`

Comment: Tentei usar no `before`, não deu certo :\

Comment: Tente chamar assim no `before`:  `$app['controllers']->requireHttps();`, não deu muito certo :\

Comment: @WallaceMaxters estou instalando e vou reformular a resposta

Comment: Te mandei uma mensagem no site, descobri como é... Adicione aí, porque não quero responder :p