# Como redirecionar apenas um diretório para http ao invés de https?

Tags: htaccess, https

Tenho uma loja magento que está configurada para usar https no front. Porém preciso que um diretório force o uso de http.

Como posso fazer isso? Tentei usar o seguinte no htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} folder 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O teu .htaccess parece estar direcionando de http para http mesmo, deve estar havendo direcionamentos infinitos devido a isto `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off`.

Creio também que `folder` deveria ser `/folder/` quando comparado ao `%{REQUEST_URI}`

Você pode criar fazer isto diretamente no `rewriterule`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Verifica se esta em uma página https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on

# Verifica se o caminho esta vindo do path folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /folder/

# Pega o que vier depois de `folder/`
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R,L]
```

Como o `RewriteCond` já verifica talvez você possa simplificar para:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Verifica se esta em uma página https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on

# Verifica se o caminho esta vindo do path folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /folder/

# Pega o que vier depois de `folder/`
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Como explique em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/188963/3635, assim se precisar mudar o nome da pasta não vai precisar mexer no `RewriteRule` basta ajustar o `RewriteCond`.

> **Nota:** `[R]` é diferente de `[R=301]`, o `R` equivale a um direcionamento temporário e o `R=301` é o redirecionamento permanente, isto pode afetar os buscadores como Google que indexa seu site.

Comment: Obrigado!! Achei q não estava indo, mas é por causa do magento mesmo, o /folder na verdade fica dentro de outras pastas, apesar de ser acessado example.com/folder

Comment: @cpbox boa, conseguiu descobrir sozinho, parabéns!