# redirecionamento Http para https via .htaccess - Godaddy

Tags: htaccess

Eu assinei um certificado SSL,instalei o certificado mas o meu site não aparece em https.

suporte me falou que tenho que alterar o arquivo .Htaccess e redirecionar para https, porém já pesquisei varias formas e nenhuma funcionou.

Eu uso a tal hospedagem Business ( América do Norte ) dedicada

Eu tentei esse codigo abaixo , mas o cadeado SSL fica verde e depois fica sem cor.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.nomedosite.com.br%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Remove o `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` e o `</IfModule>` e veja se ocorre o Erro 500.

Comment: Editei a resposta, o motivo do cadeado verde não aparecer esta explicado em *"Por que o cadeado verde ainda não aparece?"*

Comment: me responde por que o cadeado parou de aparecer do nada ?

Comment: Para de aparecer do nada porque as imagens usam lazyload, ou seja só carregam depois que a página inteira é carregada, fora que tem template é dinamico e não estático, ou seja é tudo carregado via requisições ajax e manipulação DOM. Como eu disse, o console mostra o erro "mixed content", basta apertar F12. Se sua página é HTTPS e você coloca uma imagem em HTTP dentro dela isso quebra a segurança e por isto o cadeado some, pois não é segura.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro remova o `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` e o `</IfModule>` e veja se ocorre o erro 500, se ocorrer é porque seu servidor não suporta o módulo, então solicte ao suporte que o ative.

Agora vamos ao erro, você usou:

```
{REQUEST_URI}
```

Quando **o correto é**:

```
%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Ficando assim:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.pipocaplayfm.com.br%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Uma sugestão que faço é fazer igual ao que fiz nesta resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/207031/3635, usar assim:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Pois se mudar o nome de dominio o htaccess ainda vai funcionar.

Se quiser adicionar o `www` também, acaso o usuário digite sem, então faça assim:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redireciona para o HTTPS independente do domínio
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Adiciona www. no prefixo do domínio
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Rotas
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

---

### Por que o cadeado verde ainda não aparece?

Isto ocorre porque você tem resources, como imagens dentro dá página sobre o protocolo HTTP ao invés de HTTPS, tanto que se abrir o console verá várias mensagens como esta:

> ```
> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.pipocaplayfm.com.br/' was
> loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.pipocaplay
> fm.com.br/assets/images/genres/sertanejo-universitario.jpg'. This content should
> also be served over HTTPS.
> ```

Ou seja, tem que corrigir as imagens, videos, musicas, Javascripts, css e etc para HTTPS também.

Veja por exemplo o icone esta em HTTP ainda:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://www.pipocaplayfm.com.br/storage/branding_images/DyATnJFk03RxUUwDXcyyIjEGN1x81TMtlVUrtwfN.jpeg">
```

E suas imagens também:

```
<div class="img-container">
    <img class="lazy-loaded ng-lazyloaded" src="http://www.pipocaplayfm.com.br/assets/images/genres/velha-guarda.jpg">
</div>
```

Para que seja seguro de verdade tudo tem que usar o protocolo HTTPS.

Comment: vou ver aqui e se for o que vc esta dizendo eu confirmo ...so um instante

Comment: @jhonatansantos é só apertar F12 (se for o navegador Chrome) você irá ver uma dezena de erros escritos "Mixed Content".

Comment: Eu percebi que se eu digitar www.pipocaplayfm.com.br ele não direciona para o https ...mas se eu digitar com https antes ele vai mostrar o cadeado verde.....saber pq isso man ?

Comment: @jhonatansantos aqui esta direcionando normal. Deve ser o navegador que omite o protocolo no prefixo.

Comment: Deu td certo !! vlw

Answer (score 2):

Tente adicionar a seguinte linha ao seu .htaccess (dando uma linha em branco após a linha

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule ^ https://www.seudominio.com{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: não funcionou  =/  eu fiz como vc disse . vou alterar na pergunta como eu coloquei.

Comment: ops !! apareceu o cadeado verde, mas depois ele some - sabe me dizer porque ? @DeboraCristina