# Problemas com HTTPS e Redirecionamento WWW

Tags: laravel, htaccess

Estou com dificuldades com uma coisa, tenho varias condições para atender no meu .htaccess mas nunca consigo atende-las de uma vez, apenas uma ou outra.

Tenho uma projeto em Laravel no caminho `/public_html/portal/` para a exibir preciso redirecionar o usuario para a pasta `/public_html/portal/public` até ai tudo bem, tenho um .htaccess que faz isso. Segue o mesmo abaixo:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(|chat|infinite|cliente|cadastro)\.dominio\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ portal/public/$1 [L]
```

A segunda linha serve para acessar diretamente os respectivos dominios, porque trabalho com wildcards no meu projeto.

### O problema agora

Com base nessa reescrita da linha 3 como posso realizar essas duas coisas:

1. Como posso forçar o HTTPS.
2. Redirecionar todos os acessos com `https://www.dominio.com` para `https://dominio.com`

Answer (score 2):

Como respondi em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/184459/3635, basta mudar as duas últimas linhas:

```bsh
# Redireciona para o HTTPS independente do domínio
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,L]

# Remove www. no prefixo do domínio
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,L]
```

**Notas:**

- O `%1` pega o valor do `(.*)` dentro de `^www\.(.*)`
- O `R=301` faz o redirecionamento permanente
- O `QSA` é para a querystring (se bem que talvez não seja necessário)
- O `L` é para que ambas RewriteRules não executem ao mesmo tempo

Answer (score 1):

Amigão, eu não usaria `htaccess` para redirecionar para HTTPS não. Acho mais fácil você fazer isso pela própria aplicação, através de um Middleware (se estiver usando Laravel 5).

O código se resume a isso:

```
  if (! Request::secure()) {
         return Redirect::secure(Request::path());
  }
```

Comment: Isto faz o redirecionamento 301? Falta também remover o www.

Comment: Basta seguir a lógica, daqui a 12 minutos, no meu horário de almoço, vou dar um tapa na resposta.