# Redirecionar HTTP para HTTPS no .htaccess com Let's Encrypt

Tags: html, html5, htaccess, https, redirecionamento-de-url

Não consigo de forma alguma testar se o meu endereço encontra-se em https quando o let's encrypt está instalado...

Alguma alma caridosa poderia me auxiliar a redirecionar para o https?

Eu tenho instalado na minha hospedagem UOLHost (Plataforma: Linux, Apache: Versão 2.4) o let's encrypt... E eu não sei se existe alguma relação direta (ainda estou começando minha vida em programação e sei muito pouco do inglês) entre o comando:

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
E a validação let's encrypt... Eu acredito deva ser algo relacionado a ao tipo de validação que esta sendo feita pelo encrypt que impede que o comando RewriteCond verifique o host...

Atualmente esta assim meu .htaccess

```
<files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
    satisfy all
</files>
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
ErrorDocument 400 /redirects/400.html
ErrorDocument 401 /redirects/401.html
ErrorDocument 403 /redirects/403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /redirects/404.html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    #Tentativas RewriteCond %{HTTPS} (FALHA TUDO QUE TENTEI)
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exemplo\.com\.br [NC] #verifica se falta www (MENOR IDEIA DO PQ DO NC)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.exemplo.com.br/$1 [R=301,L] #301 Moved Permanently
    #Atualmente consegue redirecionar de exemplo.com.br para https://www.exemplo.com.br
</IfModule>
```

Tentei configurar:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR] #não funcionou
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off [OR] #não funcionou
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 [OR] #não funcionou
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80 [OR] #não funcionou
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exemplo\.com\.br [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.exemplo.com.br/$1 [R=301,L]
```

sempre retorna o erro:

"Esta página não está funcionando

Redirecionamento em excesso por www.exemplo.com.br

Tente limpar os cookies.

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

**(obs.:) Eu coloquei a prova minha teoria e desinstalei o let's encrypt...**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off [OR] #funcionou
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80 [OR] #funcionou
```

Funcionou o redirecionamento mas obviamente não resolve meu problema pois não tenho um certificado sem o let's encrypt instalado.

O problema esta no trâmite da validação do let's encrypt... Preciso encontrar uma outra forma de redirecionar, talvez sem utilizar o RewriteRule.

**Outra discussão do mesmo tópico**

https://cursos.alura.com.br/forum/topico-redirecionar-http-https-com-htaccess-39055

Comment: Este ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS é suspeito, faça o seguinte, tente **desta forma** https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/184459/3635 e me avisa qual foi o resultado, observação, abra a janela de teste do navegador em modo anonimo.

Comment: Boa noite @GuilhermeNascimento. Por incrível que pareça sua resposta foi uma das primeiras que eu olhei e tentei. Não funciona... quando eu inspeciono o que ocorre é que fica redirecionando infinitamente, numa especie de "loop" 301 para https://www.exemplo.com.br... Como eu disse, o "RewriteCond" não consegue verificar se esta no "https" quando eu instalo o let's encrypt ps.: desculpe pela demora, estava jantando

Comment: Deve ter alguma coisa que vc adicionou a mais ou algum outro .htaccess em outra pasta.

Comment: Acabei de conferir.. Não tem outro .htaccess... Este comportamento não existe quando eu desistalo o let's encrypt. Redireciona normal

Comment: Você instalou o let's encrypt no teu servidor ou no localhost (nem sei se é possivel)?

Comment: Eu instalei na minha hospedagem uolhost.. o processo eh automatizado.. basta clicar em instalar e pronto, o certificado passa a funcionar (com validade de 3 meses)

Comment: Pode ser algo do uolhost que esta programado para redirecionar, vou tentar instalar o certificado em um servidor pra ver se ocorre, quando conseguir lhe aviso

Comment: Muito obrigado! So enfatizando que o problema ocorre especificamente quando eu testo "RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80" (ou algo parecido)... retirando esta linha do htaccess, redireciona normalmente o domínio digitado sem o www para o www

Comment: Creio que não tenha muito sentido checar a porta, seria somente necessário chegar o protocolo, deve ser outra coisa o problema.

Comment: então, quando eu testo o protocolo também entra no loop, eu testei tanto via porta tanto protocolo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Também uso Let's Encrypt e tive um problema semelhante, mas resolvi no VirtualHosts do Apache.

Como no seu caso, você só tem acesso ao `.htaccess`, testei alguns métodos em um servidor meu, e trouxe o que funcionou melhor.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Verifica www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

# Verifica requisições POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^POST$

# Se estiver recebendo uma requisição http de um proxy...
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http [OR]

#...ou só uma requisição diretamente do cliente
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =""
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

# Redireciona para a versão HTTPS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

Acredito que essa solução funcione também para o seu caso.

Comment: Maravilha!!!!!
Funcionou sim! Muito obrigado! (Y)